# How to create a file object from a zipfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, binary, zip

I want to create a file object from a file that is inside a zip. I don't wanna extract that file. Actually I wanna use seek method on a file that is inside a zip. My code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
input_zip = ZipFile("xyz.zip")
file_name = input_zip.namelist()[0]
input_zip.read(name)
```

But I can't use seek method on it. I wanna make it like this but without extracting the file:

```
file = open("new.txt", 'rb')
file.seek(14)
```

Comment: Have you tried to open it like shown in the documentation?

Comment: I didn't saw the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) says `seek` is supported, you just need to open it the right way (as shown there).